# Looping over an object to change values inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, tostring

I am trying to send an object to an api and my object contains arrays that I want to turn into strings. However I am having trouble returning the new object with the arrays turned to strings. My goal is to have a copy of the original object with all the arrays turned into strings.

```
const object1 = {
  a: ["TX", "CA", "LA"],
  b: 42,
  c: false
  d: []
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)){
  if(Array.isArray(object1[key]) && object1[key].length > 0){
   object1[key].toString()
  }
}
console.log(object1)
//returns the original object without `a` as string
```

Comment: `JSON.Parse(object1)`

Comment: You need to re-assign the values to a new object. `object1[key].toString()` does nothing because the result is not assigned to anything, hence the object stays as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the new value to anything, so it is being lost with each loop. Try:

```
object1[key] = object1[key].toString()
```

```js
const object1 = {
  a: ["TX", "CA", "LA"],
  b: 42,
  c: false,
  d: []
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)){
  if(Array.isArray(object1[key]) && object1[key].length > 0){
   object1[key] = object1[key].toString()
  }
}
console.log(object1)
//returns the original object without `a` as string
```

This way with every for loop, you reassign object1[key] to object1[key].toString()

Answer (score 1):

You should use join(",")

```
const object1 = {
 a: ["TX", "CA", "LA"],
 b: 42,
 c: false,
 d: []
};

 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)){
  if(Array.isArray(object1[key]) && object1[key].length > 0){
   object1[key] = object1[key].join(",")
 }
}
console.log(object1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use join on the arrays to form strings.

```js
const object1 = {
  a: ["TX", "CA", "LA"],
  b: 42,
  c: false,
  d: []
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)){
  if(Array.isArray(value)) {
    object1[key] = value.join(',');
  }
}
console.log(object1)
```

If you need to get arrays back later, use split.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a `,` after `false`. Then in the `if` statement change:

```
object1[key].toString();
```

To:

```
object1[key] = value.toString();
```

**DEMO**

```js
const object1 = {
  a: ["TX", "CA", "LA"],
  b: 42,
  c: false,
  d: []
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)){
  if(Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 0) {
     object1[key] = value.toString();
  }
}
console.log(object1)
```

**NOTE**

Pursuant to *My goal is to have a copy of the original object with all the arrays turned into strings*, if you'd like to convert `[]` to `""`, then remove  `&& object1[key].length > 0` from the `if` condition.

```js
const object1 = {
  a: ["TX", "CA", "LA"],
  b: 42,
  c: false,
  d: []
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)){
  if(Array.isArray(value)) {
     object1[key] = value.toString();
  }
}
console.log(object1)
```